# using htaccess file to emulate virtual host

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an app that functions properly on my local wamp server using the virtual host configuration seen below. I recently purchased shared hosting, but unlike my localhost, I dont have access to Apache's `httpd-vhost.conf` and instead must manipulate the site root's `.htaccess` file in order to "wire up" my application properly. 
The problem is that I do not know how to use the `RewriteEngine` to write `RewriteRules` that can emulate (to some degree) this virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sitename
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/siteroot"
    AliasMatch /(.*)\.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|html|png|jpg|jpeg|json|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf)$      "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/app/$1.$2"
    AliasMatch /rest/(.*) "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/rest/$1"
    AliasMatch /img/(.*)  "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/app/img/$1"
    AliasMatch /(.*)      "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/app/index.php"
    ErrorLog "logs/sitename_app_error.log"
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog "logs/sitename_app_access.log combined" %a
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.sitename
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/siteroot"
    AliasMatch /app/(.*)\.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|html|png|jpg|jpeg|json|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf)$  "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/app/$1.$2"
    AliasMatch /i18n/(.*)\.json$  "/wamp/www/siteroot/app/i18n/$1.json"
    AliasMatch /(.*)\.(js|css|rdf|xml|ico|txt|gif|html|png|jpg|jpeg|json|eot|woff|svg|ttf|pdf|csv)$      "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp/$1.$2"
    AliasMatch /rest/(.*) "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/rest/$1"
    AliasMatch /img/(.*)  "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp/img/$1"
    AliasMatch /(.*)      "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp/index.html"
    ErrorLog "logs/sitename_app_error.log"
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog "logs/sitename_app_access.log combined" %a
</VirtualHost>

<Directory "c:/wamp/www/siteroot">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/app">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp">
    AuthName "Login required"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthUserFile "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/adminApp/.htpasswd"
    AuthGroupFile "/dev/null"
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/siteroot/rest">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

*note that `sitename` and `siteroot` aren't the actual names of the site/filepath.

The aliasMatches are what's most important for my site to "work." This is why I think I can get by using the RewriteRules in `.htaccess`.

Even if you aren't familiar with RewriteRules, if you could tell me what the regular expressions mean, that would be of great help too! Any assistance is appreciated!